# how to pass multiple parameter to a breeze controller in the url

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

BreezeWebApiConfig
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );

i have a breeze controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Customer> Customers()
    {
        return _context.Customers;
    }


http://hostname:55946/breeze/Breeze/Customers?$filter=Country eq 'USA'
```

WORKS FINE

but when i pass 2 filter conditions as bellow, but the query just executes for the first parameter, ignoring the 2nd parameter????

```
http://hostname:55946/breeze/Breeze/Customers?$filter=Country eq 'USA' && Region eq 10
```

Comment: Eh, I don't think you can use spaces like that...  What is generating your http request?  If you are using breeze it should not be adding spaces

Comment: $filter=Country%20eq%20%27USA%27%20&&%20Region%20eq%2010

Comment: Can you show me how you are generating the query string please?  Are you using a predicate or are you just attaching that onto the end of a request?

Comment: i am just running the url in the browser. the browser adds %20 for the spaces. it brings the json data from the breeze controller in the browser, but ignores the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OData query syntax uses 'and' to join query clauses so try:

```
http://hostname:55946/breeze/Breeze/Customers?$filter=Country eq 'USA' and Region eq 10
```